# osrf/ros docker run error

Tags: docker, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I run the docker container of osrf/ros, I got the following error, and the GUI not work!

```
$ docker run -it  --security-opt="label:disable"    --env="DISPLAY"     --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"    osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-full     rqt

X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10      
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)    
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)    
  Resource id:  0x135    
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128    
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)    
  Minor opcode: 3 (X_ShmPutImage)    
  Resource id:  0x2000008
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217012/osrf/ros-docker-run-error/) by [Lmaths](https://answers.ros.org/users/22999/lmaths/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the Troubleshooting section here: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

> You may need to include
>
> --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0